# Android Options Menu

Tags: android

I tried to make option menu ,but am getting an error in the switch statement (error in all Case statements like `R.id.regid` couldn't be solved).

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
         case R.id.regid:Toast.makeText(this,"You pressed the registration      menu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;

        case R.id.enqid:Toast.makeText(this,"You pressed the Add Enquiry Menu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;

        case R.id.searchid:Toast.makeText(this,"You pressed the Search Students Menu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;

        case R.id.calid:Toast.makeText(this,"You pressed the calendar Menu for Upcoming batches",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;

        case R.id.timingsid:Toast.makeText(this,"You pressed the Batch Timings Menu for Current Batches",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;

        case R.id.courseid:Toast.makeText(this,"You pressed jlc Syllabus",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;

        case R.id.facultiesid:Toast.makeText(this,"You pressed the faculties details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;

        default:return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
     }

        }
```

**Optionmenuitem.xml**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



 <item 
    android:id="@+id/regid"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_reg"
    android:title="@string/reg"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="R"
    />

 <item
    android:id="@+id/enqid"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_enquiry"
    android:title="@string/enquiry"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="E"
    />

 <item 
    android:id="@+id/searchid"
    android:icon="@drawable/searchid"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="S"

    />

 <item 
    android:id="@+id/calid"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
    android:title="@string/upcomingbatches"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="U"
    />
 <item
    android:alphabeticShortcut="T"
    android:id="@+id/timingsid"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_clock"
    android:title="timings"
    />
 <item 
    android:id="@+id/courseid"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="C"

    android:title="JLC Syllabus"
    />
 <item 
    android:id="@+id/facultiesid"
    android:title="faculties"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_faculties"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="F"
    />

 </menu>
```

Below is the error message displayed in the console.

```
 Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_reg').
 Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_enquiry').
 Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/searchid').
 Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/search').
 Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_calendar').
 Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_faculties').

  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_reg').
  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_enquiry').
  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/searchid').
  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/search').
  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_calendar').
  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_clock').
  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_faculties').
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the code you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Remove android.R from imports if you have imported it. If it still doesn't work, try to clean the project (Project -> Clean...)

Comment: Also any other imports of R that might be there should be removed.

Comment: I removed the import.R. Now getting an error R cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Allright! I gues the error in the console has nothing to do with your code.

So you can try the following steps:

- Organize your imports by pressing <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**O**</kbd>.
- Clean your project (**Project** -> **Clean** in menu).
- Now run your app. It should work.

Let me Know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. No its still the same problem.

Comment: then make sure that you have all the resources in the `drawable` folder.

Comment: thrz a ic_launcher.png file in all the drawables. Do we need any other files in the drawable folder???

Comment: yes you need need every icon you are using in your project in the `drawable-hdpi` folder. if you dont have icons then you should remove the line **`android:icon="@drawable/...."`** in your **Optionmenuitem.xml**